# How to use functionality of INIT_CAP of SQL in rtf template?

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

In RTF Template, How to convert for example  "ABCD EFGHIJ KLMNO" into "Abcd Efghij Klmno" ?

Please share your valuable inputs on above.

Answer (score 0):

Per Oracle documentation:

> Unfortunately, initcap function is NOT supported for RTF template in
>   strings.
>
> An enhancement request raised for this, which was rejected by the
>   development team.
>
> Bug 7234142 : NO INITCAP FUNCTION IN RTF TEMPATE
>
> However, the CASE_INIT_CAP can be used for Number to Text conversion
>   functions only.
>
> Refer -
>   https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-B39D756A-C54D-4C64-A822-DD2CFFC3A54E.htm#BIPRD-GUID-2DEBF0DE-0A7E-425C-B7B2-C3A89BD7749C

You will have to handle this in the SQL that is creating the XML. Just add an additional element that is the INIT_CAP so that you have both in the XML.

BI Publisher will allow you to do all caps if that is an option:

```
<?xdofx:upper(char)?>
```

Comment: I have got the solution now. It is possible in RTF template.

Comment: Can you post the answer?